# on_notify not being fired on local or jungle testnet

Tags: smart-contract, eosio.cdt

I'm using the following contract on both my local and jungle testnets, the on_notify methods are not being fired. Everything appears to be in order, I'm hoping I've missed something obvious.

I created the table so that I can track whether the on_notify are firing on the jungle testnet.

```
#include <eosio/eosio.hpp>
#include <eosio/asset.hpp>

using namespace eosio;

class [[eosio::contract]] notifytest : public contract {
   public:
      using contract::contract;

      [[eosio::action]] 
      void addstat(name account, std::string action_text) {
          print("Adding Stat: ", name(account), " Action: ", action_text, "\n");
          add_stat(account, action_text);
      }

      [[eosio::on_notify("eosio.token::transfer")]] 
      void on_transfer(name from, name to, asset quant, std::string memo) {
         check(_first_receiver == name("eosio.token"), "should be eosio.token");
         print_f("On notify : % % % %\n", from, to, quant, memo);
         add_stat(to, "eosio.token transfer");
      }

      [[eosio::on_notify("gre111111111::issinflation")]] 
      void on_issinflation(name to, asset quantity) {
         check(_first_receiver == name("gre111111111"), "should be gre111111111");
         print("Issue Inflation ", name(to), " Amount ", quantity.to_string(), "\n");
         add_stat(to, "Issue Inflation");
      }

    private:
        struct [[eosio::table]] notifystat {
            name account;
            std::string last_action;
            int count;

            uint64_t primary_key() const { return account.value; }
        };
        typedef eosio::multi_index<name("notifystats"), notifystat> notifystats;

        void add_stat(name account, std::string action_text) {
            notifystats stats(_self, _self.value);
            auto existing = stats.find(account.value);
            print("Action added for:  ", name(account), "\n");

            if (existing == stats.end()) {
               stats.emplace(_self, [&](auto& aa) {
                  aa.account = account;
                  aa.last_action = action_text;
                  aa.count = 1;
               });
            }
            else {
               const auto& exaa = *existing;
               stats.modify(exaa, _self, [&](auto& aa) {
                    aa.last_action = action_text;
                    aa.count = ++aa.count;
               });
            }
        }
};
```

Commands used via `cleos`:

```
cleos --url https://jungle2.cryptolions.io:443 push action eosio.token transfer '[ "gre222222222", "gre333333333", "1.0000 EOS", "Test" ]' -p gre111111111

executed transaction: 84fc4c054918649b0ce4b875b4b0922684619f4d76abbbe5b8a901811d1781ff  136 bytes  275 us
#   eosio.token <= eosio.token::transfer        {"from":"gre222222222","to":"gre333333333","quantity":"1.0000 EOS","memo":"Test"}
#  gre222222222 <= eosio.token::transfer        {"from":"gre222222222","to":"gre333333333","quantity":"1.0000 EOS","memo":"Test"}
#  gre333333333 <= eosio.token::transfer        {"from":"gre222222222","to":"gre333333333","quantity":"1.0000 EOS","memo":"Test"}

cleos --url https://jungle2.cryptolions.io:443 push action gre1111111p2 addstat '[ "gre111111111", "Test Action Stat"]' -p gre1111111p2

executed transaction: f8ff8d05aec829fd8ccba9a909c8f04ca065fcabf724390cf0c0b839cb94d523  120 bytes  217 us
#  gre1111111p2 <= gre1111111p2::addstat        {"account":"gre222222222","action_text":"Test Action Stat"}
>> Adding Stat: gre222222222 Action: Test Action Stat

cleos --url https://jungle2.cryptolions.io:443 get table gre1111111p2 gre1111111p2 notifystats

{
  "rows": [{
      "account": "gre111111111",
      "last_action": "Test Action Stat",
      "count": 1
    },{
      "account": "gre222222222",
      "last_action": "Test Action Stat",
      "count": 1
    }
  ],
  "more": false
}
```

The stats output above is from me testing the table and `add_stat` method works. It's just the on_notify which aren't firing and updating the table.

Comment: what are you expecting from "const auto& exaa = *existing;" ? Just do stats.modify(existing, _self, [&](auto& aa) {..}.

Comment: It was just a test contract I knocked up from other contracts, it is indeed superfluous :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there's one vital piece when using `on_notify`, the action being monitored must call `require_recipient(<your contract account name with on_notify>)`. This sends a copy of the action to that account.

Comment: Are you able to get notified of `eosio.token::transfer` actions? I'm having no success with that

Comment: Guys at EOS Cafe pointed me to an implementation they are using: https://github.com/eoscafe/tipped/blob/master/contract/tipped.hpp . You need to make sure the contract with the `on_notify` is either the `to` or `recipient` of the transfer

Comment: @JasonBert the link is broken (404)

Comment: "the action being monitored must call..." -- that means that if I'm monitoring eosio.token's transfer method, then that method must call require_recipient()... but we have no control over that!